# Function doesn't increase distance

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $A \subseteq X$ with $A \neq \varnothing$, and $$f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad\text{such that}\quad \left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\leq d(x,y),\ x,y\in A.\tag{$\ast$}$$

Let $$f_1, f_2 : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$be functions such that $$f_1 (x) = \sup_{a \in A}(f(a)-d(x, a))\quad \text{and}\quad f_2 (x) = \inf_{a \in A}(f(a)+d(x, a)).$$

Could you tell me how to prove that $f_1|_A=f_2|_A=f$ and that

if $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ doesn't increase distance (property $(*)$ ), then $g|_A=f \iff \forall x \in X f_1(x) \le g(x) \le f_2(x)$

My main problem is that I don't know how restriction of $f_1, f_2$ to $A$ affects the functions.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I did not see that the question was actually different...Ignore my stupid closing request. Apologies again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint for the first part. If $x,a\in A$ then $f(a)-d(x,a)\le f(x)\le f(a)+d(x,a)$. Since this inequalities hold for each $a\in A$, we see that $f_1(x)=\sup f(a)-d(x,a)\le f(x)\le\inf f(a)+d(x,a)=f_2(x)$. For the proving of the opposite inequalities, consider the case $a=x$.

Comment: Shouldn't the inequalities go more like this: $f(a)+d(x,a)\le f(x)\le f(a)-d(x,a)$

Comment: I suppose I should show that $f(x) \le f_1(x)$ and $f(x) \ge f_1(x)$, the same for $f_2$, and take $ \sup, \inf $ of $f(a)+d(x,a), \ \  f(a)-d(x,a)$ at some point.

Comment: But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have corrected the inequalities and extended the hint, see above.

Comment: Ok, I've already solved the first part. Could you tell me something about the second part?

Comment: The necessity is obvious. For the sufficiency you should show that  
$f(a)-d(x,a)\le g(x)\le f(a)+d(x,a)$ for each $a\in A$.

Comment: By obvious you mean that it results from the first part? As for sufficiency, I know that $g(a)-d(x,a) \le g(x) \le g(a)+d(x,a), \ \ a,x \in X \ \ $ How/Why can I estimate it using $f$?

Comment: Yes, in $(\Leftarrow)$ case, from the first part we have that $f_1(x)=f(x)=f_2(x)$ for each $x\in A$. In $(\Rightarrow)$ case, you have that $g(a)=f(a)$ for each $a\in A$.

Comment: But why do we have $f(a)=g(a)$ for $a \in A$? That's what I've been meaning to ask you.

Comment: By the conjecture $f|A=g|A$.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook $\Rightarrow$ for $\Leftarrow$. Thank you.